# Мультиязычность на сайте, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Меня не интересует реализация сервис-провайдеров или middleware, как сделать 'переключалку' языка я знаю. Я впервые сталкиваюсь с задачей сделать сайт мультиязычным, потому хочу получить грамотный/е ответ/ы на вопрос/ы.
Сайт крутится на Laravel v8, я знаю что для перевода статического контента используется директива lang в resource'ах, ну и соответственно, значения из возвращаемых массивов.

Ещё обозначу: разрабатываю интернет-магазин.

1. Как правильно переводить весь сайт? То есть для каждой локали в папке текущей локали должны быть подпапки согласно папкам в ресурсах видов? Мол, если у нас views/shop/single/single.blade.php, то для его перевода в папке текущей локали должна быть тоже такая директория и файл lang/en/shop/single/single.php ?
   (Я хочу понять, как правильно сделать). И так для всего статичного контента который я хочу перевести? А как быть с категориями на сайте, которые хранятся в БД? Делать разные таблицы согласно существующим на сайте локалям?
2. Возможно, имеет смысл 'дублировать' файлы видов для разных локалей, изменяя статический текст на другой язык? Я знаю, что в некоторых случаях магазины отображаются в разных странах вообще по-разному, то есть шаблоны отличаются. Вопрос следующий: насколько такой вариант эффективный и правильный, и как в таком случае его реализовать, то есть создавать в видах подпапки локалей, или?
3. Как реализовать базу данных для товаров? Естественно, бана в яндексе нет (в гугле есть), однако, какого-то единственно верного решения я найти не смог (естественно, я плохо искал, потому - прошу помочь вас). Из того что я понял, в зависимости от установленной локали мы должны получать товары, и, список товаров на сайте для разных локалей может различаться, мол в русской версии такие товары есть, а на английской - нет. Ещё, как быть с отзывами для товаров, понятно что нужно реализовать отзывы отдельной таблицей, и, по моему предположению - связывать с какой-то конкретной локалью глупо? То есть отзывы как для en так и для ru например будут выводиться одни и те же?

*Знаю что схожие вопросы на сайте уже есть, однако конкретно того, чем я интересуюсь - нет. Ссылки на те топики кидать не нужно (!только если вы убедились что я слеп, и не увидел там ответы на свои вопросы).*

**Заранее благодарю!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Мол, если у нас views/shop/single/single.blade.php, то для его перевода в папке текущей локали должна быть тоже такая директория и файл lang/en/shop/single/single.php

Это лишнее. Большая часть фраз у вас будет дублироваться рано или поздно. Нет смысла переводить каждую view в отдельности. Лучшей практикой будет поделить переводы логически (например, resources/lang/en/currencies.php - тут все по валютам, .../billing.php - тут все по оплате и тп).

> А как быть с категориями на сайте, которые хранятся в БД?

Все зависит от категорий. Если они у вас статичные (меняются раз/два в жизни), то можно в условной колонке `name` (в таблице `categories`) хранить путь до перевода (прим. `categories.dresses.name`). Это самый простой, но плохой вариант. И скорее всего, категории меняются у вас все-таки чаще.

В данном случае я вижу два решения:

1. На каждый язык создавать свою колонку (name_ru, name_en). Звучит плохо. Но других вариантов вы вряд ли найдете. Тут можно в модели будет создать виртуальное свойство `getNameAttribute()`, с помощью которого определять текущий язык пользователя/системы и возвращать уже нужное значение
2. Аналогично первому варианту, но названия вынести в отдельную таблицу `category_names`. Из плюсов - названия не мозолят глаза при работе с таблицей вручную (такой себе плюс, но все же). Из минусов - +1 запрос при выборке, + 1 сущность, которую нужно поддерживать и правильно синхронизировать.

> Делать разные таблицы согласно существующим на сайте локалям?

Крайне не рекомендую так делать потому, что:

1. У вас появятся проблемы потом с foreign ключами (если таблицы будут самостоятельными).
2. Если же fk ключи вы собираетесь дублировать между таблицами, то готовьте код для синхронизации. В случае ошибки в его работе, вам нужно будет сливать данные (если таблицы наполняются отдельно друг от друга)
3. Ок, предположим у вас есть две таблицы: `categories_ru`, `categories_en`. В категориях же что-то лежит, правильно? Пусть будут товары (`products`). Предполагаю, что в табличке `products` будет некое поле `category_id`. Куда оно должно вести? На `categories_ru`? На `categories_en`? Это полностью противоречит канонам Laravel по наименования полей. Я, допустим, как новый разработчик, придя на ваш проект, после вас, возьмусь за голову и не буду понимать что и куда относится

> насколько такой вариант эффективный и правильный, и как в таком случае его реализовать, то есть создавать в видах подпапки локалей, или?

Все зависит от задачи. Если сайты для разных стран действительно разные, то это хорошая идея. Хранить можно примерно так:

1. /resources/views/en/auth/login.blade.php - страница, которая на разных локалях должна выглядеть по-разному
2. /resources/views/common/auth/some.blade.php - страница/компонент, которая(ый) выглядит одинаково везде

Если остановитесь на этом способе, то рекомендую перевод хранить все-таки в lang, а не во views. Во views буду дубли. Если решите изменить текст, то менять его придётся в нескольких фалах. С lang такой проблемы не будет.

Если же сайт выглядит одинаково, то лучше не дублировать views. При изменении одной из них, вам придется переносить изменения и в другую view.

> Из того что я понял, в зависимости от установленной локали мы должны получать товары, и, список товаров на сайте для разных локалей может различаться, мол в русской версии такие товары есть, а на английской - нет

Если хранить имена товаров в разных колонках (`name_ru`, `name_en`), то фильтр не будет сложным:

```
select * from products where name_en is not null
```

> Ещё, как быть с отзывами для товаров, понятно что нужно реализовать отзывы отдельной таблицей, и, по моему предположению - связывать с какой-то конкретной локалью глупо? То есть отзывы как для en так и для ru например будут выводиться одни и те же?

Я не знаю задачи, но, предполагаю, что вам нужно будет хранить локаль в двух местах:

1. У пользователя (таблица `users`). Нет смысл показывать русскую версию американцу
2. В сессии текущего пользователя, если он не аутентифицирован. При определении локали будет примерно такой код:

   $lang = 'ru'

   if(auth()->check()) {
   $lang = auth()->user()->lang ?? $lang;
   } else {
   $lang = session('lang') ?? $lang;
   }

По отзывам - нет смысла определять локаль для каждого отзыва. Достаточно сделать нужный фильтр по БД, если хотите показывать отзывы по отдельности:

```
SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE reviews.user_id = users.id AND users.lang = $lang)
```

Да, есть шанс, что человек выбрал английский язык, написал отзыв на русском и заново переключился на русский и там написал на английском, но, думаю, это не так критично